# Finding the woocommerce result price in folder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering where I can find the result price of a product in the .php file in the WooCommerce folder.

This is because I want to give the result price a custom discount when it shows in a pdf file from the mail you have got from placing a order.

I am currently using the "WooCommerce PDF Invoice" plugin by RightPress.
The support told me to look into the files myself, but I can't find them.

Pim

Comment: What you want to edit in price section?? I dint understand your question well?Could you please explain more about your need?

Comment: Yes ofcourse,
For my webshop I want to add a pdf to the email that will be send after an order from a customer.
The thing is, that I want to give the given price result a 20% discount. 
The problem is that I want to add a extra custom field to show the price with discount.

You can see the example right here: 
http://prntscr.com/i8l3gv
http://prntscr.com/i8l4fp

Comment: Which plugin are you using for PDF?

Comment: You are using premium plugin right?Then You can ask plugin support for your issue.

Comment: Yes but the support told me to look it by myself..

Comment: I think You need to contact your plugin author because you want custom fields on pdf right?That pdf templates are created by that plugin authors.

Comment: I can add custom macro's but I have tried alot of it. http://prntscr.com/i8n1j4